# Custom Table Cell Loads blank

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

I have a table view with custom cell that i am trying to populate with data saved in core data storage. I am getting the right number of cells appearing but they are blank. the cod below is what i am using to call the cells. I did find several questions similar to this but none were any help in my situation.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:           (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WTHAITableViewCell";
WTHAITableViewCell *cell = (WTHAITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
NSManagedObject *location = [locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[WTHAITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Display recipe in the table cell
cell.nameLabel.text = [location valueForKey:@"name"];
cell.longLabel.text  = [location valueForKey:@"longitude"];
cell.latLabel.text  = [location valueForKey:@"latitude"];


return cell;

}
```

this is the code that is saving the data.

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newLocation = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SavedLocations" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newLocation setValue:self.LongLable.text forKey:@"longitude"];
[newLocation setValue:self.LatLable.text forKey:@"latitude"];
[newLocation setValue:self.name.text forKey:@"name"];

NSError *error = nil;

if (![context save:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);

}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Like i said i get the correct number of cells but all are empty. Any help would be great! If you need any extra info let me know.

Comment: What exactly is your custom TableViewCell ? Has it a xib? Did you check the `location` values?

Comment: Question. Have you designed your Cell using xib ? Or, Programmatically ?

Comment: have designed the cell using story boards. Larme- how do i check the values other than loading them??

Comment: Try this if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WTHAITableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

Comment: place a break point in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and check the `location` values.

Comment: Mohit that didn't help.

Comment: @user3462838 problem is with your custom cell. it is not loading properly. data is fine i think

Comment: Bharat the values are correct for location. so it must be the cell not loading correctly right? any ideas because i am going batty!

Comment: do you add cell identifier at attribute inspector ..?

Comment: the cell identifier is customCell

Comment: if cellIdentifier is customCell in storyboard then you have to pass that customCell as cell identifier in code also in cellForRowAtIndexPath...

Comment: It was a case of looking at it too long and looking past the answer!! I simply changed `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WTHAITableViewCell";` to `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";` It Works Now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plz try to change the line

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";
```

here customCell means the name which you given as cell Identifier in attribute inspector in storyboard

may this fix your problem.